# Gtag not defined

Tags: javascript

Trying to add Gtag script and some conversion tracking code using Javascript without script tags. I'm getting *gtag is undefined and appendChild of null* errors in console.

Gtag script is below

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-xxxxxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxx');
</script>
```

This is how I'm trying to implement the gtag script and conversion code.

```
// Create gtag Script
var gtagScript = document.createElement("script");
gtagScript.type = "text/javascript";
gtagScript.setAttribute("async", "true");
gtagScript.setAttribute("src", "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-xxxxxx");
document.head.appendChild(gtagScript);

// Add gtag config
gtagScript.onload = function() {
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxx');
};

// Add gtag conversion pixel
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-xxxxxx/hdyesanxalasis',
      'value': BOLD.order.total / 100,
      'currency': 'BOLD.order.currency',
      'transaction_id': 'BOLD.order.id'
  });

// Get order items
var content_ids = [];
BOLD.order.line_items.forEach(function(item, i){
content_ids[i] = "" + item.platform_product_id;
})
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"Trying to add JavaScript without script tags..."_?...

Comment: Also, note that the loading of the script is done ***asynchronously*** so most likely the script has not finished loading before `gtag` is being referenced down below.

Comment: @War10ck I added better explanation. Perhaps if I remove the async declaration, the problem should be solved?

Comment: @user3512391 correct.

Comment: @user3512391 Yes, the first snippet should work if you remove the `async` attribute. Same for the second I believe if you remove the `.setAttribute('async', true);` statement.

Comment: @War10ck gtag is still undefined. How do one convert the // gtag config // block of code into a script? I think that is what this is missing

Comment: @War10ck Perhaps wrapping the conversion block of code in in gtagScript.onload = function() {} would work. I can see the gtag script loaded on the page.

Comment: The reason why this is not working is not only timing: it's because the gtag function is defined locally inside the onload of the script, but it's called outside of it. You should either move everything inside the onload or move everything outside of it. You could also attach the gtag function to the window, but in that case timing would become very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. I removed `.setAttribute("async", "true");` and then wrapped the conversion pixel in an onload event: `gtagScript.onload = function() {};`

```
// Create gtag Script
var gtagScript = document.createElement("script");
gtagScript.type = "text/javascript";
gtagScript.setAttribute("src", "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-xxxxxx");
document.head.appendChild(gtagScript);


//Make sure gtag script above is loaded
gtagScript.onload = function() {

// Add gtag config
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxx');


// Add gtag conversion pixel
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-xxxxxx/hdyesanxalasis',
      'value': BOLD.order.total / 100,
      'currency': 'BOLD.order.currency',
      'transaction_id': 'BOLD.order.id'
  });

// Get order items
var content_ids = [];
BOLD.order.line_items.forEach(function(item, i){
content_ids[i] = "" + item.platform_product_id;
})

};
```

Comment: If you look at the official documentation you will see that there is no code waiting for the script to be loaded: you can keep the async, but without inserting all the code in the onload of the script. So after the appendChild line you just go with window.dataLayer etc. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs